# Как объединить ввод 3-х переменных в один input() для дальнейших операций с ними?

Tags: python, input, переменные

Задача производить операцию за один ввод данных, а не по очереди как:

Введите оператор: +

Введите первое число и так далее...

---

Примерная идея:

```
num1, oper, num2 = input('Ввод:').split()
if oper == '+':
    ans = num1 + num2
    print(ans)
```

Вывод:

> Ввод: 2 + 2
>
> 22

Проблема в том что оно распознает числа как строки

Comment: `num1, num2 = map(int, [num1, num2])`

Comment: @splash58 А oper получается остается локальной переменной?

Comment: oper остается строкой